# Objective C Get Data Out of Completion Block and Parsed in Outside Class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app with code that is similar to many networked apps. I want to get the json payload out of the completion block, into an array, and enumerated through by a different class to create objects. Then I want those object to populate a tableView.

My problem is that the solution I have requires a lot of properties of type NSMutableArray in the completion block. I have only seen demos that have the comment //do something with the data. It's just that it's hard to deal with parsing, calling methods on other classes and populating an array from within the completion block. I can, but the code becomes spaghetti.

What is a good architecture for this?

```
if (request) {
        [client sendTwitterRequest:request completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            if (data) {
                // handle the response data e.g.
                NSLog(@"DID data request start");
                NSError *jsonError;
                NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
[self handleJSON:json];
                }
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
```

I create a helper method like so

```
-(void)handleJSON:(NSDictionary*)dictionary{

    for (NSDictionary *jsonDict in dictionary) {

        id value = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"text"];

        NSLog(@"string text %@", value);

    }
```

But then I get

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key text.'

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "search_metadata" =     {
        "completed_in" = "0.041";
        count = 15;
        "max_id" = 1013632106432360448;
        "max_id_str" = 1013632106432360448;
        "next_results" = "?max_id=1013632026514079744&q=%23trump&include_entities=1";
        query = "%23trump";
        "refresh_url" = "?since_id=1013632106432360448&q=%23trump&include_entities=1";
        "since_id" = 0;
        "since_id_str" = 0;
    };



    statuses =     (
                {
            contributors = "<null>";   
            coordinates = "<null>";   
            "created_at" = "Mon Jul 02 03:55:01 +0000 2018";   
            entities =             {
                hashtags =                 (
                                        {
                indices =                         (
                            20,
                            28
                        );
                        text = GOODWIN;
```

When I fast enumerate to get dictionaries in an array, the array count is 2 - one for `search_metadata` and the other for `statuses`. Within `statuses` there are several tweets. I've never encountered anything like this before.

Comment: Call a function from the completion handler?  Just do what you do with any large chunk of code, break it down into smaller tasks.  Create object initialisers that accept dictionaries so that they can instantiate themselves from the JSON.  Harder, but worth considering is moving to Swift where you can use Codable to simplify JSON deserialisation

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying that and just ending up with more spaghetti. I just keep creating mutable arrays as properties and trying to figure out how to get them over to a better place to parse them.

Comment: I would create a whole bunch of classes that represent each object in your JSON.  You then pass the top-level JSON dictionary to a constructor for the top level class and it does the work of instantiating the rest of the objects under it, again passing the relevant dictionaries to the other class constructors.

Comment: Yes, I have that. But how to get the JSON over? I'm creating a helper method to put each dictionary in an array index. Let's see what happens next. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Perhaps you could show some of your code.  I don't understand why you need a number of arrays.  Your JSON is in `json`, so you would say something like `TopLevelObj *topLevel = [TopLevelObj alloc [initWithJSON: json]]`

Comment: Can you show some of the structure of the JSON?  To access the dictionary values you want `[jsonDict objectForKey:@"text"];` or just `jsonDict[@"text"];`